# Understanding $p$-rank, $p$-Sylow subgroup, $2$-part, odd and even part of a group.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

As the title says, I would like to be clear about what each of those terms mean in an ideal class group setting. I would like someone to correct me where I am wrong. The reason for this clarification is at the end. Maybe some ideas on how to approach the problem would also be great.

Let $G = C(\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_K})$ be the class group of a maximal order where $\Delta_K\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, a fundamental discriminant.

1. The **odd part** of the class group is the subgroup $H$ of $C(\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_K})$ whose elements $h_i$ have **odd orders in $G$**
2. The **even part** of the class group is the subgroup $H'$ of $C(\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_K})$ whose elements $h'_i$ have **even orders in $G$**
3. The **two part** of the class group is the subgroup $F$ of $C(\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_K})$ whose elements $f_i$ have **powers of two orders in $G$** (shouldn't this be called something like 'power of two-part'?)
4. The **$p$- rank** of $C(\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_K})$ is the largest integer $k$  such that $C(\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_K})$ has an Abelian subgroup of order $p^k$
5. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $\lvert C(\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_K})\rvert$ , i.e. $p$ divides $h_{\Delta_K}$. If $p^k$ divides $h_{\Delta_K}$ and $p^{k+1}$ does not divide $h_{\Delta_K}$ then any subgroup of order $p^k$ is a **$p$-Sylow subgroup** of $C(\mathcal{O}_{\Delta_K})$.

Consider the following two examples taken from [here, page 29](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/32572/Nicole.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

1. $\Delta_K = -93920213643973848047$
   $h_K = 5602080000$
   $2$-part $=(2,2,2,2,2,8)$
2. $\Delta_K = -106994885997905465007$
   $h_K = 6485160000$
   $2$-part $= (2,2,2,2,2,2)$

In example 1, the $2$-rank is $6$ and the size of the $2$-Sylow subgroup is $8$.

In example 2, the $2$-rank is $6$ again and the size of the $2$-Sylow subgroup is $2$.

**Questions**

1. Is everything that I wrote correct, esp. the sizes of the $2$-Sylow subgroups in the examples?
2. Essentially, given the factorization of $\Delta_K$, I would like to restrict the size of the $2$-Sylow subgroup to $2$. It is well known that if $\Delta_K=-pq$ and $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=-1$ then it can be restricted to a size of $2$.

I want to figure out the conditions on the $\Delta_K$ prime divisors when $\Delta_K=-p_1\cdots p_n$ and $\Delta_K=-p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_n^{e_n}$ so that the $2$-Sylow subgroup has size $2$ like in example 2.

Comment: 1,2,3 - since G is finite abelian, you know that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/p_i^{e_i}\mathbb{Z}$ (here pi can be the same). The p-part of a finite abelian group is the product over which $p_i=p$. This means your 1,3 are correct, but 2 is not (since if you multiply an element of odd order with one with even order, the product also has even order - but you want to capture the elements without the odd order part)

Comment: 4,5 - 5 is correct, 4 is not - it's the largest integer $k$ where the class group has an **elementary** subgroup of order $p^k$.

Comment: Your size of 2-sylow subgroup is wrong: - Example 1: 2-sylow subgroup is precisely $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^5 \times \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, so the size of 2-sylow is precisely $2^5×8=2^8$, and the 2-rank is 6 like you said.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I see the mistakes.

Comment: @Pig Would you have any idea about Question 2? I made a new post here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908077/how-to-guarantee-non-existence-of-order-4-elements-in-class-group-of-a-maximal-o